# How to extract a column of data and replace with foreign key?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, constraints, database-normalization

How do you extract a `column (varchar, allows null)` of data into a new table and replace it with a foreign key?

Steps as I know them:

> 1. Create a new table with an incrementing PK column and data varchar
>      column.
> 2. Use [insert-into-select](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) to copy the data into the new
>      table.
> 3. Update/add a foreign key column in the original table???

How would I make the foreign key, step 3?

Comment: What do you mean "replace with a foreign key"?..

Comment: I think Adam means "normalize by turning the column's entries into references to a lookup table created by taking the distinct values from the column and storing them in a new separate table"

Comment: @CraigRinger Correct that is exactly what I'm looking to do.

Answer (score 2):

The already existent table `t`:

```
create table t (s text);
insert into t (s) values ('a'), ('a'), ('b'), (null)
```

The to be referenced table:

```
create table s (
    s_id serial primary key,
    s text
)
```

Copy the distinct and not null values to the referenced table:

```
insert into s (s)
select distinct s
from t
where s is not null
```

Create the foregin key id column:

```
alter table t
add column s_id int
```

Populate the new column with the foreign key ids:

```
update t
set s_id = s.s_id
from s
where t.s = s.s
```

Create the constraint:

```
alter table t
add foreign key (s_id) references s (s_id)
```

Drop the now unnecessary column:

```
alter table t
drop column s
```

Final result:

```
\d t
    Table "public.t"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 s_id   | integer | 
Foreign-key constraints:
    "t_s_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (s_id) REFERENCES s(s_id)

\d s
                        Table "public.s"
 Column |  Type   |                    Modifiers                     
--------+---------+--------------------------------------------------
 s_id   | integer | not null default nextval('s_s_id_seq'::regclass)
 s      | text    | 
Indexes:
    "s_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (s_id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "t" CONSTRAINT "t_s_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (s_id) REFERENCES s(s_id)
```

Test the constraint:

```
insert into t (s_id) values (3);
ERROR:  insert or update on table "t" violates foreign key constraint "t_s_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (s_id)=(3) is not present in table "s".
```

A sample query:

```
select s_id, coalesce(s, 'null') as s
from t left join s using(s_id);
 s_id |  s   
------+------
      | null
    2 | a
    2 | a
    1 | b
```

Answer (score 0):

> In step 2 when creating inserting the data into new table make sure
>   you are not adding duplicates. Also you can add constraints to not add
>   duplicates.

Also before you do 3.

> 2a. Alter existing Table add a new column which **will be** refrencing
>   the PK of your new foreign table.
>
> 2b. Populate the new column by joining your existing table and your
>   new table on the *varchar* column and update with ForeignTable ID.
>
> 2c. Drop the varchar column in your existing table.

Now you are ready for step 3 to add foreign key.

```
ALTER TABLE ExistingTable
ADD CONSTRAINT yourFK
FOREIGN KEY (yourColumnNameID)
REFRENCES yourNewForeginTable(ColumnNameID)
```